# Why element getBoundingClientRect() values condition is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, css

I have `.square` element when I move my mouse it should be moved with the mouse. Almost everything is good when I move my mouse normally but when I move my mouse fastly on the right and bottom side, Then the `.square` box goes to the down or right side and makes the scrollbar.

> How can I make my code better than now **OR** How to fix the problem?

**[NOTE]:** Transition should have

```js
let square = document.querySelector(".square");

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  if (square !== null) {
    let x = e.pageX;
    let y = e.pageY;

    square.setAttribute("style", `top: ${y}px; left: ${x}px`);

    let getBottom = square.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    let getRight = square.getBoundingClientRect().right;

    if (getBottom > window.innerHeight) {
      square.setAttribute("style", `bottom: 0; left: ${x}px`);
    }

    if (getRight > window.innerWidth) {
      square.setAttribute("style", `top: ${y}px; right: 0`);
    }

    if (getRight > window.innerWidth && getBottom > window.innerHeight) {
      square.setAttribute("style", `bottom: 0; right: 0`);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  transition: .01s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: _ I move my mouse slowly but when I move my mouse fastly on the right and bottom side, Then it gets down/ right the square box._ Can you explain this with more detail?  I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by defining a transition on the square element's position in CSS,  combined with setting the position of the square before reading its current position:

1. Setting the position immediately to the mouse move position:

   ```
    square.setAttribute("style", `top: ${y}px; left: ${x}px`);
   ```

   can move the square out of the viewport and create scroll bars if the mouse is less than the length of the square's side away from the bottom or right of the browser window.
2. Reading the position of the square next:

   ```
   let getBottom = square.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
   let getRight = square.getBoundingClientRect().right;
   ```

   returns the updated position of the square if there is no transition, but with the transition returns where the square is now, before the transition starts. Since the square is not outside the window yet, none of the conditional statements using its old position detect that it will end up outside the window.

The easiest solution is to remove the CSS transition - keeping it at 0.01 second is less than monitor update refresh time and not particularly useful.

Getting the square's position *once*, before updating its position is another solution.

In either case it may be smoother to update the position of the square at most once, with the position where it transition to.

---

In this code used to find an answer, the `html` element's `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` properties are a [special case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) of these properties and reflect the size of the view port excluding scroll bars. The transition timing is set to 0.05 seconds to avoid stroboscopic effect from screen refresh:

```js
let square = document.querySelector(".square");
const HTML = document.firstElementChild;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  if (square !== null) {
    let domRect = square.getBoundingClientRect()
    let x = e.pageX;
    let y = e.pageY;
    x = Math.min( HTML.clientWidth - domRect.width, x);
    y = Math.min( HTML.clientHeight - domRect.height, y);
    square.style.top = `${y}px`;
    square.style.left = `${x}px`;
    //square.setAttribute("style", `top: ${y}px; left: ${x}px`);
  }
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  transition: .05s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```